# Does uninitialized pointer evaluate to true, false, or results in undefined behavior?

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, undefined-behavior

I couldn't find in the C standard, if uninitialized pointers evaluate to true, false, or result in undefined or implementation defined behavior? For example:

```
{
    int *p;
    if (p)
     do_sth();

}
```

Comment: UB, of course.­

Comment: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/995714)

Comment: Context matters!  If the pointer is defined inside a function (as it seems to be since the next statement is an `if` testing it), the result is undefined behaviour.  If the pointer is defined outside any function, then it is default initialized to a null pointer and will compare false.

Comment: And if it is in the function and has had its address taken, it resides probably in memory and its contents are indeterminate and value can change at any instance of use but it would behave as if it was true or false at any given moment.

Comment: Can someone point to me the specific section in the C standard? I can't find it. And no, it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: And no, using uninitialized local variable is not an undefined behavior (e.g. adding two initialized int variables - it is just some garbage value). De-referencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined.

Comment: Why would there be a section in the standard that defines the boolean state of a pointer?   There is no section that defines the truth of three-sevenths either.

Comment: @user3124390 no, simply reading any uninitialized values invokes UB, no need to dereference the pointer, because there are many architectures that don't allow that. Please read the duplicate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code **it's undefined behavior** to access any uninitialized values in C, regardless of its type (except for `unsigned char`).

Since a pointer is not a `unsigned char` type, the behavior is undefined.

Note for implicit initialization, like putting the definition in file scope, or defining it with `static` storage class specifier, causes the object to be zero-initialized by default.

For more information, see [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11962457/5958455)

Comment: Not quite so simple

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I know what you mean.

Comment: The value obtained from accessing an uninitialized `unsigned char` is unspecified, even if the access does not result in undefined behaviour.  An `unsigned char` defined at file scope (or inside a function with storage class `static`) is initialized to 0.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Your comment was slower than my awareness of those missing points :)

Comment: It's what comes of repeating myself without using copy'n'paste :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: When using gcc, the result of accessing an uninitialized `unsigned char` may be worse than Unspecified, even when the access is done using a character pointer.  Under gcc, reading all bytes of an uninitialized object and storing all those values into the bytes of another uninitialized object may cause gcc to treat the second object as uninitialized even though all of its bytes have been written.